# System.Windows.Forms.Timer keeps on running

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I need to show a message after 10 seconds of form load. 
I am using the below code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SetTimeInterval();          
}

System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public void SetTimeInterval()
{           
    MyTimer.Interval = ( 10 * 1000);
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);            
    MyTimer.Start();    
}

void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TIME UP");           

    MyTimer.Stop();
    MyTimer.Enabled = false;
}
```

Tried using MyTimer.Stop() and MyTimer.Enabled = false, but messagebox keeps displaying every 10 seconds. How do I stop it after the first instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that `MessageBox.Show()` is a *blocking* call. So `MyTimer.Stop()` is only called *after you close* the `MessageBox`.

So until you closed the `MessageBox` there will pop up new ones every 10s. The simple solution is to change the order of calls:

```
void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    MyTimer.Stop();
    MyTimer.Enabled = false;
    MessageBox.Show("TIME UP");           
}
```

So the timer is stopped as soon as you enter the event handler, before displaying the message box.

Comment: Right answer :-)

So in the code this line:

    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

You do not need to specify the "new <delegate>". The following is cleaner:

    MyTimer.Tick += TimerEventProcessor;

Comment: @rene Thanks. Which one is more adivisable? MyTimer.Stop() or MyTimer.Enabled = false; ?

Comment: @JanDavidNarkiewicz Thank you.I will implement that. Can you please tell me the difference b/w using new and not using?

Comment: Actually the underlying code is identical with and without the "new' allocating the delegate. C# 2.0 introduced "delegate inference" -- kind of explains what the compiler does -- it infers you meant to create a delegate there so it writes the code for you under the covers. A lot of examples were never cleaned up to use delegate inference so will see it down the 1.0 and 1.1 way in a lot of places.

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest this method
go to theform.designer.cs
writhe this code

```
this.timer1.Enabled = true;
this.timer1.Interval = 10000;
```

and do this in ur .cs file

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("msg");
}
```

that work perfectly for me.

Comment: How is this related to the OP's question?

Comment: this does not stop the timer